# Understanding the error - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, cross-domain, http-status-code-500

When I try to load an external script server rejects the request  `net::ERR_ABORTED 500`.

[image]

Just want to understand why this is happening. is it because the external script is not configured to load on other domains? or is it my server blocks loading external script?

My HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <script 
  src="https:/link-to-external-website.com/path-to-script></script>
<title>JS Bin</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   test page
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"is it my server blocks loading external script?"_ - how could it _possibly_ do that, when your problem is on the client side ... _"is it because the external script is not configured to load on other domains?"_ - we can't tell you that, you'd have to ask the provider of that external script.

Comment: "The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. This error response is a generic "catch-all" response." - Mozilla

Comment: so you cannot identify what is wrong unless you have  a more specific error code or can review the code for adaptivity issues

Comment: Another idea, your url is `https:/link-to-external-website.com?s=www.mysite.com&sz=1"` so I am guessing that the c query is for CORS. Try loading a URL like `somewebsite.com/script.js` that is not dynamic, and set the CORS so that any site can access it.

Comment: So is `https://link-to-external-website.com` under your control? If yes, you have to debug the server, why it's throwing a 500 error with that request. Oftentimes, a 500 error results from some exception which is not handled in your code but only in the default error hander.

Answer (score 1):

It has been mentioned in a comment, but I'll also start with a reminder that an Status Code of 500 is an "internal server error", this is explained well in [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500). You mentioned `When I try to load an external script server rejects the request`, but the server isn't blocking the request, it just isn't handling it.
If you have a look at the response headers there is `X-Frame-Options` which is set to `SAMEORIGIN`. This means "you can still use the page in a frame as long as the site including it in a frame is the same as the one serving the page", see [X-Frame-Options from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#syntax) (again).

In any case, the server logs will help debug this efficiently.

It looks like test.html is something you might be running locally. If you suspect a CORS issue you could [add a hosts file entry](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-edit-hosts-file) for a domain that is the same as where you are trying to load the script from.

e.g

You are trying to load `eCRSEAL.ashx?s.example.com`

Your [hosts entry](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-edit-hosts-file) might look like

```bash
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

This way the origin header will be the same and you won't (shouldn't) get a CORS issue. Though, that is no guarantee that the server won't give a 500, only the logs of the server will help with that.